# Cypher: matching nodes that have both child A and child B

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following relations describing `(person1)-[:LIKES]->(person2)`.

```
X1 LIKES Alice, Bob, Carol
X2 LIKES Alice
X3 LIKES Bob, Carol,
X4 LIKES Alice, Bob
```

What is the Cypher query if I want to find all persons that likes both Alice **AND** Bob? (should return X1 and X4)

I have tried `MATCH (p1)-[:LIKES]-(p2) WHERE p2.name IN ['Alice', 'Bob'] RETURN p1, p2`. However, this returns X1, X2, X3, and X4, who like Alice **OR** Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an article in the Neo4j knowledge base on how to write queries that [perform match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/), like what you're trying to do here.

Applying the first solution to this case, one query you could use is:

```
MATCH (p1)-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person) 
WHERE p2.name IN ['Alice', 'Bob'] 
WITH p1, count(DISTINCT p2) as likesCount
WHERE likesCount = 2
RETURN p1
```

There are a few notable changes here.

First, we're using a label :Person on `p2`, and I'm assuming you have an index or unique constraint on `:Person(name)`, so the lookup by name is quick.

For each matched `p1` node, if the number of matching `p2` nodes is 2, this means both Alice and Bob were matched from the same `p1` node.

If we wanted to generalize this approach, for example if we accepted a list parameter of names of some unknown size, we would compare the count to the size of the input list instead.